drill into concrete wall first holes in my life
I live in a new building in Germany (2022 year). I have a hammer drill + concrete bits + metal detector.
I have 2 drawings of my room (it is the same room).
I wanna drill to orange and green areas. Both walls are concrete walls. Middle wall does not have sockets/switches. Orange wall has socket+switch. Red wall is a drywall and this wall is shared with bathroom (and there is toiler + shower).

Does it safe to drill anywhere in Green wall?
I want to drill near corner of two walls(left and middle). Is it possible that wires are there?
Is it possible that pipes/tubes exist inside middle(green) wall? E.g maybe they are going to neighbor apt?
Orange (left) wall has a socket and a switch. But as I understand I just need to avoid drilling above and below them, right? So I draw in orange color where I want to drill. Is it safe?

I have a metal/stud detector and it shows wires only below switch and below sockets. In all other places it shows metal each interval something like 10 cm, but I think it is a rebar.
I want to attach cat house and some stuff for cat on these walls. Depth of some dowels are 5cm.



all is it possible? questions have a yes answer ... all is it safe? questions have a no idea answer
